# SolrCloud Kubernetes Deployment and Connection

Tags: java, kubernetes, solr, lucene, solrj

I have a Kubernetes-based SolrCloud deployment based on Marketplace Solr Kubernetes deployment. The details of the implementation can be found in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/k8s/solr.

For my use case, I'm trying to use GitHub actions to update/create a SolrCloud collection:

1. If the collection does not exist, create it
2. If the collection exists, update it based on schema changes

I have the following services running:

```
# kubectl get services
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
ilb-service            LoadBalancer   XXX            XXX           8983:30072/TCP      92d
kubernetes             ClusterIP      XXX            <none>        443/TCP             92d
solr-1-solr-exporter   ClusterIP      XXX            <none>        9983/TCP            92d
solr-1-solr-headless   ClusterIP      XXX            <none>        8983/TCP            92d
solr-1-solr-svc        ClusterIP      XXX            <none>        8983/TCP            92d
solr-1-zk-client       ClusterIP      XXX            <none>        2181/TCP            92d
solr-1-zk-headless     ClusterIP      None           <none>        2888/TCP,3888/TCP   92d
```

For local development, I've port-forwarded the solr-1-zk-client like so:

```
kubectl port-forward \                                                                                                                                          
        svc/solr-1-zk-client \
        --namespace default 2181
```

I'm trying to use the following script to test if I can add a document:

```java
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBHttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import picocli.CommandLine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

@CommandLine.Command(name = "SolrManager", description = "Creates a solr collection using a provided config.", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
public class SolrManager implements Runnable{
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SolrManager.class);

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-z", "--zkHost"}, paramLabel = "ZKHOST", description = "zkHost to connect to")
    String zkHost;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkACLProvider" },  paramLabel = "zkACLProvider", required = true)
    String DzkACLProvider;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkCredentialsProvider" },  paramLabel = "zkCredentialsProvider", required = true)
    String DzkCredentialsProvider;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkDigestUsername" },  paramLabel = "zkDigestUsername", required = true)
    String DzkDigestUsername;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkDigestPassword" },  paramLabel = "zkDigestPassword", required = true)
    String DzkDigestPassword;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkDigestReadonlyUsername" },  paramLabel = "zkDigestReadonlyUsername", required = true)
    String DzkDigestReadonlyUsername;

    @CommandLine.Option(names = { "-DzkDigestReadonlyPassword" },  paramLabel = "zkDigestReadonlyPassword", required = true)
    String DzkDigestReadonlyPassword;


    public static void main(String... args) {
        CommandLine.run(new SolrManager(), System.err, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.setProperty("zkACLProvider", DzkACLProvider);
        System.setProperty("zkCredentialsProvider", DzkCredentialsProvider);
        System.setProperty("zkDigestUsername", DzkDigestUsername);
        System.setProperty("zkDigestPassword", DzkDigestPassword);
        System.setProperty("zkDigestReadonlyUsername", DzkDigestReadonlyUsername);
        System.setProperty("zkDigestReadonlyPassword", DzkDigestReadonlyPassword);
        System.setProperty("basicauth", Dbasicauth);

        LOG.debug("Connecting to Solr cluster: " + zkHost);
        CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(Collections.singletonList(zkHost), Optional.empty()).build();
        client.setDefaultCollection("test");
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc.addField("id", "1234");
        doc.addField("content", "A lovely summer holiday");

        try {
            client.add(doc);
            client.commit();
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this to work, but I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" picocli.CommandLine$ExecutionException: Error while running command (SolrManager@53fdffa1): org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: http://solr-1-solr-0.solr-1-solr-headless.default:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1948)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:2172)
    at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:2550)
    at picocli.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:3008)
    at picocli.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:2959)
    at SolrManager.main(SolrManager.java:62)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: http://solr-1-solr-0.solr-1-solr-headless.default:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:125)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:46)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.directUpdate(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:581)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.sendRequest(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:1076)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:934)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.request(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:866)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:156)
    at SolrManager.run(SolrManager.java:83)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at: http://solr-1-solr-0.solr-1-solr-headless.default:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.doRequest(LBSolrClient.java:369)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.LBSolrClient.request(LBSolrClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.lambda$directUpdate$0(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:555)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: solr-1-solr-0.solr-1-solr-headless.default: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:571)
    ... 10 more
```

I expected that all the requests would be sent to the Zookeeper Service that I had port-forwarded, but it seems that the CloudSolrClient client is trying to call the `http://solr-1-solr-0.solr-1-solr-headless.default:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1` server from my local development machine.

How would I solve this issue? I'm new to kubernetes. Will I have to wrap my Java application in a Docker container and execute my code from the same cluster so that it can talk to the other services in there? I'd really appreciate some help as to how to do this properly in a Kubernetes deployment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to port-forward 8983 also.  The solr client doesn't go through Zookeeper 100%.